# Why openldap password policy pwdMinLength doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, ubuntu-14.04

I have defined openldap password policy overlay The `pwdMinLength: 9` is not working, i'm still able to create user with password less < 9 character, The password Password Policy Overlay on OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 14.04

```
    dn: cn=MyOrgPPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=zarigatongy,dc=youtube.com
    cn: MyOrgPPolicy
    objectClass: pwdPolicy
    objectClass: device
    objectClass: top
    pwdAttribute: userPassword
    pwdMaxAge: 3024000
    pwdExpireWarning: 1814400
    pwdInHistory: 4
    pwdCheckQuality: 1
    pwdMinLength: 9
    pwdMaxFailure: 4
    pwdLockout: TRUE
    pwdLockoutDuration: 600
    pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
    pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
    pwdMustChange: TRUE
    pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
    pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

The Other pilicies are working fine for example for failed attempt user get locked because of `pwdMaxFailure: 4`

created the user.ldif file for creating the user

```
dn: uid=test123,ou=Users,dc=zarigatongy,dc=youtube.com
cn: test123
mail: zarigatongy@youtube.com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: top
sn: test123
title: Demo User
uid: test123
userpassword: test1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supplying pwdCheckQuality=1  which will accept the password if it's unable to check it for some reason. pwdMinLength only works if the password isn't hashed.  So if it's unable to check MingLength, the password will be accepted.

Most likely you're passing the server a hashed password when creating it.
http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-ppolicy  should help, specifically ppolicy_hash_cleartext

Comment: updated the question with the user.ldif

Comment: not sure if copy paste error but userPassword vs userpassword

Comment: @paul is right: in order to check your ppolicy you have to change test123's password with `ldappasswd`